# array object with named key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have found this code...

```
var newEntry, table = [];
newEntry = {
    id: '321',
    price: '1000',
};
table.push(newEntry);
alert(table[0].id);
```

It works like expected. However I need to add more than one entry, like this...

```
var newFont, newColor, table = [];
newFont = {
    family: 'arial',
    size: '12',
};
newColor = {
    hex: 'red',
};
table.push(newFont);
table.push(newColor);
alert(table[0].font);
```

**Problem**

- I don't want to write `table[0].family`.
- Instead I would like to write `table['font'].family`.
- It's a named key instead of just a number. It would be better if the settings increase.

Comment: Retagged as JavaScript since this is not related to jQuery in any way. It is purely about JavaScript. jQuery is just a JavaScript library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want an object, not an array:

```
var settings = {
    font: {
        family: 'arial',
        size: '12'
    },
    color: {
        hex: 'red'
    }
};
alert(settings.font.family);    // one way to get it
alert(settings['font'].family); // another way to get it
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, arrays can't have named keys, but you can change `table` to an object and use named keys.

```
var newFont, newColor, table = {};
newFont = {
    family: 'arial',
    size: '12',
};
newColor = {
    hex: 'red',
};

table.font = newFont;
table.color = newColor;

console.log(table['font'].family);
console.log(table.font.family);
```

Comment: *"In JavaScript, arrays can't have named keys"* Yes, they can. Standard JavaScript arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), they're just objects with some special behavior. `var a = []; a.foo = "bar"; console.log(a.foo);` will show you `"bar"`.

Comment: well what you're saying is true and I agree but in practice you would distinguish between objects and arrays, only using an array if fit for purpose. I probably should have said arrays _shouldn't_ have named keys in the context of what OP wants.

Comment: I add named keys to arrays all the time. For instance, if I want something that's ordered but I also want to look up entries by a key property, I'll usually do `a = []; a.index = {};` and then add the objects to the array and the index (using the key). It's fine provided you don't expect it to survive a round trip through JSON, since JSON's arrays don't have a notation for this.

Comment: Looks like we could debate this for some time. Thanks for the comments, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this : `table['font'] = newFont;` ?